# How can I wrap a new pattern around a 3D object in a photograph?

Tags: photoshop, image-manipulation

I have a problem with setting a pattern on sofas. The image below is a pattern that I set on a sofa:

[image]

as you can see, the pattern comes from up to down in a straight line. This is wrong; I need it to covert the corners, do the indent and ....

for better understanding the result I want, please see the below image. I saw this on a website, and as you can see, it isn't in a straight line — it goes in the corners, rotates, and exactly gets the shape of the sofa.

[image]

This is exactly what I need to do but I don't know how. How can I do this in Photoshop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you do it manually or by building a 3d model in a third party 3d modeling tool (or from a 3d scanned point cloud converted to a surface) and applying textures in Photoshop using Photoshop Extended's 3d model support.  As far as I know, Photoshop doesn't have an automatic tool for figuring out geometries of a scene by image processing magic. (And even if it did, I don't think the current state of the art can determine with that fine of accuracy without at least a series of images to work from taken from different angles.)

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful answer . you said I have 2 ways , Manually, How can I do it Manually?  2- 3d model , Could you explain it more?

Comment: Manually meaning you rotate and crop the texture to match the angle by hand using the perspective warp.  I've not actually done the 3d approach as I've always done my texture mapping in SoftImage rather than Photoshop.  I believe the help documentation for it is fairly straight forward, but the model creation would be the harder part and is really beyond the scope of this site (and really any Q/A as it is going to be a rather involved process.)

Comment: You said " from a 3d scanned point cloud converted to a surface" . Do I need a 3d scanner for this ? - after lots of research , I find out making a 3d model from furniture is a very hard work and needs alot of time . is there any simpler way to do it ? maybe with Photoshop or other plugins ?

Comment: Could you tell me a good way to learn 3d modeling ?

Comment: Yes, No and No.  A 3d scanner is the easiest way to make a model, but still generally requires some specialized knowledge for refining it in to a surface.  There is not a simpler way to do it as what you are trying to do needs to understand the geometry of the object.  If you don't know 3d modeling, the "easier" way is manually trying to correct for these angles using the perspective tools, but it will still be hard and time consuming.  And no, there is no easy way to learn 3d modeling.  It is its own entire field and is arguably considerably more complex than Photoshop to learn.